How to generate a random number between 0 and 1 while excluding a subrange
How can I generate a random number between 0 To 1 while excluding a subrange. E.g. from 0.2 to 0.5?

Generate a number in the range [0, 1-(MAX-MIN)] and if the generated number is greater than MIN add MAX to it.   where MIN and MAX are the limits of your exclusion range, in your example 0.2 and 0.5 respectively.

Assuming the intended distribution of said random number is uniform ...

This way you will get the most uniform distribution:
# 0.0     0.2      0.5           1.0
#  |       |XXXXXXXX|             |
# 0.0     0.2            0.7
#  |       |              |

n = random.uniform(0.0, 1.0 - (0.5 - 0.2))
if n >= 0.2: n += (0.5 - 0.2)


import random

def random_excluding_subrange(exclude_start, exclude_end):
    # Determine the sizes of the allowed subranges
    lower_size = exclude_start  # [0, exclude_start)
    upper_size = 1 - exclude_end  # (exclude_end, 1]

    # Total size of the allowed ranges
    total_size = lower_size + upper_size

    # Determine whether to generate in the lower or upper subrange
    r = random.uniform(0, total_size)

    # Generate in the lower subrange
    if r < lower_size:
        return r

    # Generate in the upper subrange
    return exclude_end + (r - lower_size)

# Test the function
for _ in range(10):
    print(random_excluding_subrange(0.2, 0.5))


Just a code dump is not likely to help future visitors. Explain what you did and why.
